# How to calculate the distance of a point after a rotation

Tags: trigonometry

I'd like to learn how to calculate the distance of a line, from it's previous or intial position, to a new position after a rotation is applied.

The distance can be calculate on the interception at the bottom line as seen in the image example attached to this post.

Center pivot is at the center of the rectangles.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let: $A$ and $A'$ the two final points of the line ( before and after a rotation of angle $\theta$), $B$ the midpoint of $AA'$ and $O$ the center of rotation.

The triangles $ABO$ and $A'BO$ are equals, The angle in $B$ is $90°$ and the angle in $O$ is $\theta/2$.  Can you do from this?